# Does move always copy the data?

Tags: rust, compilation, llvm

Let's say we have a function that passes a relatively large piece of stack-only data to another function, like this:

```
fn a() {
    let arr_a: [i32; 1024] = [1, 2, 3, ...];
    b(arr_a);
}

fn b(arr_b: [i32; 1024]) {
    // ... do stuff with arr_b here
}
```

In Rust terms, when `b` gets called, `a`'s `arr_a` will be *moved* into `b`'s `arr_b`. Under the hood, will the entire array *always* be copied on the stack, or is it possible the compiler will optimize that by simply using the data of `arr_a` as it is, at the memory address it is, without copying it? If the latter, which part of the compiler should be responsible for that? LLVM?

*Note: I know we can *guarantee* the array's data doesn't get copied by using a reference/slice for example, but that's not what this question is about.*

Comment: In the Rust Virtual Machine, a move is always a copy. LLVM may optimize it out (usually not across function boundaries if not inlined). I remember this already asked, but I don't find where.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That makes perfect sense to me. Inlining should be a major factor, I guess. I'm curious under what circumstances LLVM may decide to (not) optimize it, in both cases - inlined and not inlined.

Comment: Well… it's complicated. But the source is on github, you can look.